# Captioning two side by side figures outside float environment

Tags: captions, footnotes, includegraphics

I want to put two figures in the footnote of my document. I need to write a caption without a label for each figure. The problem is that the figures are located vertically when I add the `\captionof*{}` command. Does anybody have any idea to put the figures side by side?

I am using the following code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\footnote{text text text text text text text

\begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{Fig.png}
    \captionof*{figure}{first figure}
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{Fig.png}
    \captionof*{figure}{second figure}
\end{center}    

}

\end{document}
```

and the result is as the following

[image]

Comment: Please each image and its caption in a minipage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @leandriis said in the comments, I put each figure in a `minipage` environment. In this way, the figures are located side by side.
The modified code with minipage environment is as

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\footnote{text text text text text text text

\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}\vspace{15pt}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{Fig.png}
    \captionof*{figure}{first figure}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}\vspace{15pt}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{Fig.png}
    \captionof*{figure}{second figure}
\end{minipage}

}

\end{document}
```

and the result of the above code is as

[image]